# show Asp.net website to client without having domain or web hosting

Tags: asp.net, web, web-deployment

I have developed  website on Asp.net for my client . I want to show him progress of work . I have no domain or web hosting to show him . Is there any possibility to show my website built on Asp.net to my client ??Also I have used ngrok but its another case its not wirking . Any other software or free domain or web hosting???

Comment: Can you use something like TeamViewer or Webex?  It will allow you to show your screen to the client.  Unless, of course, you need them to actually play with the website

Comment: i have heared about TeamViewer but nothing about webex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [azure free websites](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/develop/net/aspnet/).

Other than that, you can host the website on you own computer and give your client your ip address (you may have to play around with port forwarding and windows firewall).